# Display menu items horizontally

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to follow probably the most basic HTML tutorials and not having any luck getting my menu items to display horizontally.

I'm creating an ASP MVC 4 site out of the box, and trying to start with a simple `nav` tag and display each `li` horizontally. There literally isn't anything to this site yet so I'll display the full cshtml/css below:

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Search</li>
                    <li>Create PENSGC</li>
                    <li>Display Excpetions</li>
                    <li>Create Exception</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>               
            @RenderBody()   
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

Most of this is basic, out-of-the-box stuff.

```
html {
    background-image: url("/Images/Swiftnet-Background.jpg");
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    height: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white; 
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
}

#body {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

/* menu */
nav {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

    ul#menu li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Looks horizontal to me http://jsfiddle.net/zq9VP/ What exactly isn't working? Do you meant that the `li`s run on to multiple lines when the browser window is narrow?

Comment: They display inline to me as well. Of course, even inline elements will wrap to a new line if there isn't enough width in the viewport and there's no code telling it to do otherwise.

Comment: What's the deal with the #body element and ul#menu?  These look like typos to me.  There are no body and menu ids in the html code.  The height: auto is duplicated.  If you want to eliminate some of the browser's default formatting, just use one of the reset css files instead of sprinking a bunch of padding: 0 and margin: 0 declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, why you don't user this?

```
<nav>
    <span>Search</span>
    <span>Create Exception</span>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to edit your **CSS** code

```
nav, ul {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.